# Metadata call multiple times in breeze can it reduce?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm stuck in this point and can't continue.

I am using **breeze** with **knock-out** I have only one entity manager but still metadata call  every query  can we reduce the call of metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Your first option is to call EntityManager method [fetchMetadata()](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_fetchMetadata), it returns Promise, and when it resolves, EntityManager doesn't query metadata anymore, so you need something like that:

```
var _manager=new breeze.EntityManager("/breeze/<controller>");
_manager.fetchMetadata().then(function() { 
  <your queries here>
});
```

also, you can then export metadata from this manager to some variable via _manager.metadataStore.exportMetadata() to some variable, and import it to all your new managers.

But there is another way, of doing it in more syncronous way, without fetchMetadata promise waiting, you can generate script with metadata on server and then load it to your application with , and then import this metadata to all your managers. [Here is the link](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/load-metadata-script)